# jar path for running dataflow job on airflow

Tags: python-2.7, google-cloud-platform, airflow, dataflow

first of all ,I am new to airflow. What i am trying to do is to run dataflow job using airflow.
searched many links found that we need to create a jar file and then using airflow script we can run it . Does anyone know where this jar should be placed ,means on google cloud bucket or local path. Can we directly run template through airflow

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Google Cloud Dataflow operator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/dataflow_operator.py) contributed to the Airflow project which you can find here.

There is an example in the code on how to specify a Dataflow job; the path to your jar is defined there (see line 50 in the code). You will need to give it the path to your jar on the machine you are scheduling from (so the local path on your Airflow machine).

Comment: While your answer indicates how to execute Apache Beam code on Cloud Dataflow inside an Airflow DAG, it seems to me that it would be much simpler to store the templated code on GCS and launch the Dataflow template from a DAG without having to provide a binary.

Comment: Sure, that is a possibility. It does, however, not answer the question asked.

Comment: On the contrary, I think the question specifically asks for a way to execute a Dataflow template from Airflow, as pointed by OP's last sentence.

Comment: Templates are also part of the operators available in Airflow and can be found in the link (line 148).